# Scrollpanel's scrolls doesn't come up on first page load

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a Dialog and there is a ScrollPanel inside it. The problem is scrolls doesn't come up on first page load and when I resize the Dialog, scrolls appears.

```
 <p:dialog id="detailsDialog"
                  header="Details"
                  widgetVar="detailsDialog"
                  resizable="true"
                  appendToBody="true"
                  draggable="true"
                  >
            <p:scrollPanel>
                <h:outputText value="#{myController.html}" escape="false" />             
            </p:scrollPanel>
        </p:dialog>
```

Comment: Add width and height attribute for to define initial size of dialog

Answer (score 0):

You may have to consider using scrollPanel mode 'native' as below:

`<p:scrollPanel mode="native">
    <h:outputText value="#{myController.html}" escape="false" />

</p:scrollPanel>`